# Where can I find SQL Developer Database examples (scripts) to add data to practice?

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, scripting, oracle-sql-developer, powerbi

Where can I find SQL Developer Database examples (scripts) to add data to practice?

I require SQL scripts that will add tables and data on those tables in order to practice with Power Bi.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the forum! I don't know why this has been downvoted - IMHO, it's a perfectly legitimate question for dba.stackexchange! You might want to [look here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/install-sample-schemas) also.

Comment: Thank you very much !

Answer (score 2):

The example schemas are now on Github.

https://github.com/oracle/db-sample-schemas

Comment: Thank you ver much!